# Using printf to output a variable

Tags: bash

```
km@Karls-MBP ~/dev/form (master) $ SS="----\n----"
km@Karls-MBP ~/dev/form (master) $ printf "$SS" | head -1
bash: printf: --: invalid option
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
```

I'm attempting to output the second last line from a variable. It seems to interpret the string as a flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell `printf` there are no more options:

```
printf -- "$SS"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the `\n` to be interpreted by the shell, use this:

```
printf -- "%s" "$SS"
```