# Set Variable to ls command output

Tags: macos, bash, environment-variables

I'd like to create a variable from the output of a bash command. How does one create a variable out of the output of the command "ls /Users".

Variable creation does not work in this case:

`users=$(ls /Users)`

`printf 'users'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using printf to output a variable](https://superuser.com/questions/1360901/using-printf-to-output-a-variable)

Comment: [Don’t parse `ls`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) Just use the shell. Also, using scalar variables for multiple file names is a bad idea. (What if they contain spaces?) `users=(/Users/*); users=("${users[@]#/Users/}"); printf '%s\n' "${users[@]}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable creation works. What did not work is your second statement (printf). This works for me:

```sh
users=$(ls /home)
echo "${users}"
```

I am using `/home` only because I am on Linux. In your case you should still user `/Users`.